# CliXml Serialization/Deserialization lose type

Tags: powershell, serialization, powershell-4.0

The small function here under show that during serialization / deserialization  operation I lose the `Scriptblock` type of one of my parameters.

```
Function CliXMLPOC ([String]$p1, [scriptblock]$p2)
{
  # $PSBoundParameters is an automatic var containing bound parameters
  Write-Host "BEFORE Members are : $($PSBoundParameters["p1"].GetType()), $($PSBoundParameters["p2"].GetType())"
  $serialized = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($PSBoundParameters)
  $deserialized = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($serialized)
  Write-Host "AFTER Members are : $($deserialized["p1"].GetType()), $($deserialized["p2"].GetType())"
}

CliXMLPOC "Toto" {write-host "coucou"}
```

The result gives :

```
BEFORE Members are : string, scriptblock
AFTER Members are : string, string
```

Can anybody explain this and help me to retreive the expected result ?

```
BEFORE Members are : string, scriptblock
AFTER Members are : string, scriptblock
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is a bug. I can recreate the issue and can't find a work-around. I have submitted a bug report to Connect [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/1202386/clixml-system-management-automation-psserializer-deserialize-fails-to-recreate-scriptblock-type) so feel free to add more info to it.

Comment: The bug still exists in PowerShell V5.0